# No webpage was found for the web address: XXX IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I had created an Asp.NET Core Web Application
My app is running on debug 100%, But on publish and host on my server.
the views in subfolder are not found

-- Structure: 
Views 
-- Setting 
---- Donors --> views in this folder are not found on IIS 
---- Facility --> views in this folder are not found on IIS

Comment: did u used asp.net core 2.x?

Comment: Yes, Asp.Net core 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The ape.net core 2.x project have by default `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` to `true`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

if you look at publish output folder you will see the dll with name `.PrecompiledViews.dll`
and this dll contains all your views.

2) If you want to forcefully publish your views then edit your `.csproj` file and modify below lines

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

By this modification you will see all your views to your publish folder.

Comment: Please view the solution might be it help you

Comment: It's work, my views are shown in folders and all links in my app is now work !! Thank you very much ..

Comment: glad to hear you have get rid from your problem. :)